# How to make sure of user's privacy in my app?

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, database, privacy, home-server

I want to develop an app where I want to give user's at most privacy to their data. I need a database and server to run my app. Are there any instances of AWS/GCP not being trustworthy regarding user data ? How can I achieve the user data privacy and security ?

I came up with the following solutions

1. use one cloud provider for server and another cloud provider for database (database data encrypted with keys in server cloud provider ).
2. develop my own database and server at home.

Which is most cost and performance efficient and quick to production in both scenarios.

Comment: This is not possible. Unless you host it on your own internet connection, someone else can always be forced to retrieve the data or being hacked, and in that case you literally cannot do anything to prevent the data to be comproised in worst case scenario.